# Batch file to create 3 scheduled tasks running mondays every third week

Tags: date, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

As I tried to explain in the title; 
I have a batch file that creates 3 scheduled tasks that takes backup. It creates them by importing an exported pre-made task. I want the batch file to create them so that the first task runs 1. coming Monday. 
e.g.: The first task run November.4.2013. The second task runs a week later November.11 and the third one runs another week after that November 18. Then the next week the cycle "restarts".

I know how to insert the date into the pre-made tasks, but I cant find out how to get the 3 dates that I want.

This might be to much for a batch file, but if anyone have some ideas it would be much appreciated.

edit: Using windows 7

Comment: Are you running this on a Windows machine? How about posting your batch script

Comment: To create/import the tasks I use:
schtasks /Create /RU %username% /RP %var% /tn "Backup week1"  /XML "c:\sqlm\Week1.xml" /f
I don't think the rest of the script I use is not relevant for this question. As it does simple tasks as editing hosts file and coping the temporary textfiles used to create the backup scripts.

Comment: This tasks needs to be run all months or just one time each?

Answer (score 2):

The task scheduler has a concept of "<n>th <day_of_week> of the month". If you create the task by hand, you could choose something like this. When I did it (1st Monday of November) and exported the task to XML, here's the trigger that I saw.

```
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2013-10-29T07:32:13.0631789</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByMonthDayOfWeek>
        <Weeks>
          <Week>1</Week>
        </Weeks>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Monday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <Months>
          <November />
        </Months>
      </ScheduleByMonthDayOfWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
```

You ought to be able to effect what you need by using something like this in the XML you're importing, changing `<Week>1</Week>` to 2 and 3 for the other tasks.

**EDIT**

Here's the trigger code to run every three weeks on Monday.
This would be a recurring task. You'd just need to change the StartBoundary date for each one.

```
<Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2013-11-01T09:24:37.1425194</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Monday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>3</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
```

If the "backup" consists of a single file or directory, another alternative would be to have the backup script determine which backup is the oldest, rename it, do the backup, then delete the old backup once it's finished.

This command will get the oldest (last write time) matching file/dir and save it in the environment variable `BACKUP_DEST`. You could use that in your backup command.

```
FOR /F %%b IN ('dir /o-d /tw /b \\backup_server\backups\hostname\*.zip') DO SET BACKUP_DEST=%%b
```

One advantage of doing it this way is that scheduling would be greatly simplified. Just run it every week. You'd have to precreate three "empty" backups (or use the three that you already have).

Comment: Thanks for reply!
Yes, I have considered that option. I could use this and trigger on week one and four. But some months (e.g. desember this year) have five mondays. Also, the tasks trigger a "manual" backup and each task deletes the old one. So when the months change week 1 will run two weeks in a row. And I would prefer to have the backup taken in the order that I are imposed to make them run. If somethings go wrong I might get blamed for not making the backup run as imposed.
So, as far as I can see I have to use the weekly and every 3. week trigger.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you want. When do you want the task to run? Every 3rd week? The 3rd week of every month?

Comment: I might make a "prompt for input" of the starting dates of the tasks in the batch file. That way I can insert the input into the XML files. But experience has shown that less user input is less chance of error.. Also, I'm getting annoyed for not being able to make this happen.

Comment: I want the three tasks to run over three weeks and then start over(overwriting previous data) Week one runs the first week creating backup. The next week the next task starts, creating a second backup (week2) The third week the last task run(creates third backup) then the first task starts again next week, deleting old week1 data and writes a new one.. And then the backup cycle goes on..

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thank you!